# Python speed 32 v 64 bit Windows issue

Tags: python, windows, performance, 32bit-64bit

I've been having performance issues when moving apps between 32 bit windows 7 and 64 bit windows server 2008, both with similar processors.  I wrote a trivial program to test memory allocation performance to see the difference.  It shows that making lists on 64 takes almost 10 times as long as 32 bit windows.  Using python 2.6.5 on 32 and 2.6.6 on 64.  What could be causing the problem?  I wrote a little 'c' program to do the same thing and it showed the 64 bit server going faster.  So what is going wrong?

```
#silly python memory allocation test
from datetime import datetime
import random

d = datetime.now()
listo = [1] * 300000
del listo
print datetime.now()-d
d = datetime.now()
listo = [1] * 3000000
del listo
print datetime.now()-d
d = datetime.now()
listo = [1] * 30000000
print datetime.now()-d
```

result on 32

```
0:00:00.002000
0:00:00.024000
0:00:00.166000
```

result on 64

```
0:00:00.031000
0:00:00.156000
0:00:02.672000
```

Is there some outstanding problem with Python and memory peformance on 64 bit windows?

**64 Windows 2008 R2 Server setup**

4 CPU, 16GB Memory, 20GB C drive, 10GB/s Network Xeon X5570 @ 2.93GHz

**32 Windows 7 pc**

2 CPU, 2GB Memory, 500gb C drive, 1 Gb/s network Core 2 duo @ 3.00ghz

Comment: Care to use better timing, like http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html. Thanks

Comment: I just used timeit for your three examples on Windows 7 64-bit with Python 2.6.5. I had to add a del so that it wasn't shortcutting the actual creation. My times match up pretty well with your 32-bit times. How fast is your computer and how much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by use of virtural machine software on the windows server.

Comment: @BenSapp I don't really have any details on why.  But running same code without virtual server software performance was pretty much the same for 64 and 32 bit python.  I'm using VMware corporate stuff on windows server 2010 64.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm on a Server 2008 R2 VM on VMWare (free version).  The reason I ask is I've been banging my head against django (OSQA) on python 2.7 for about a week trying to get it to perform better.  When I hit a page the cpu usually spikes to 50% on the VM and average response time is 400-700ms.  When I run native on Win7 64 (32bit python) it has hardly any effect on CPU and decent (~130ms) response time.  Quite a difference!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it is so much longer, but a bit more time you should expect because in this example the program allocates double of the memory in the 64 bit mode, as in the 32 bit mode since python uses 32/64bit pointers in its lists.

This may be different in C when you are still using 32bit datatypes.

Comment: Yes, it could be that he's just crossing some threshold that causes the GC to run.

Comment: @Gabe - or pushes the dataset out of the L3 cache.

Comment: @atzz: He's creating a list of 30M integers, which is 120MB on a 32-bit machine. That's one hell of an L3 cache! :)

Comment: @Gabe - yeah, I guess I overlooked a couple of orders of magnitude :)

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem with Python 2.7 and 64 bit. I run a program which in 32 bit Python gave memory overflow on a smaller computer. I was interested of if my big RAM would be used. And certainly it was. Up to maximum 10 GB and the machine hanged up. I had to switch of the power supply and restart the computer.

Comment: I've used up to 92 giga bytes with 64 bit python on windows server 2010.  That was the maximum the server blade could support so I had to change my code to use less memory.  10giga bytes usage has nerver given me any trouble.